# API Json in symfony form

Tags: json, api, symfony, symfony-forms

i'm creating an application in symfony 2.8 (with php5.4) and in my form (that i'm building) i want to display a list of a projects through an API in json format. 
Now i'm stuck, and i don't know how to do this. 
I know the database of the API there is a table "projects" and i want target the column 'name' to display names of projects
here's my code:

```
/**
* @Route("/form")
*/
public function formAction(Request $request)
{

  $url = 'https://website.com/projects.json';
  $get_json = file_get_contents($url);
  $json = json_decode($get_json);

  $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('Project', 'choice') // <-- ???
    ->add('send', 'submit' ,array('label' => 'Envoyer'))
    ->getForm();
  $form->handleRequest($request);

  return $this->render('StatBundle:Default:form.html.twig', array('form' =>  $form->createView(), 'project' => $json));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the choice as second argument as array as example:

```
$jsonAsArray = json_decode($get_json, true); // with true return an array

$builder->add('Project', 'choice', array(
    'choices'  => $jsonAsArray,
    // *this line is important, depends of the data*
    'choices_as_values' => false,
));
```

More info [in the doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html).

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks it's works for me if i set value **'choises_as_values' =>false**

Comment: hi @countrystores you are welcome! I update the answer with your comment

Comment: Hi @countrystores if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.